# try-catch block used while smtp exception need to display an error message in the local server

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, smtp, try-catch

Catch block used whenever there is an exception while using `smtp` port,but it will throw exception thats fine,`it will take a very long time` and also the exception message will be directly shown in the code itself,requirement is to display an error message while executing in the `localserver` and shouldnot come to the code. It should `throw exception` whenever the `server` is down or `invalid email Id` or change in `smtp port`,Conclusion is the error message should not come directly to the code.It should display an error message and stop the `application` which should not `hang`.

```
 protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    //string vv;
    //vv = (string)Session["FID"];
    DateTime sdt = DateTime.Today;

    SqlCommand cmd4 = new SqlCommand();

    int flag=0;


   String test = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd.MM.yyy");
   for (int i = 0; i <= GridView1.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
   {

       string toemail = GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Text;
       string FID1 = GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Text;
       GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[i];
       CheckBox Ckbox = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("CheckBoxMark1");
       if (Ckbox.Checked == true)
       {

           sendMail(toemail);
           flag = 1;
           //ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "validation", "<script language='javascript'>alert('Email send Succesfully')</script>");
       }

       if (flag == 1)
       {
           ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "validation", "<script language='javascript'>alert('Email sent  on " + test + "')</script>");

           cn.Open();
           //cmd4.CommandText = "Insert into TrackingFaculty_det  (EmailsentDate)  values (@EmailsentDate) WHERE FID=@FID";
           cmd4.CommandText = "update TrackingFaculty_det SET EmailsentDate=@Email WHERE FID=@FID  ";
           cmd4.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
           cmd4.Connection = cn;

           cmd4.Parameters.Clear();


           cmd4.Parameters.Add("@Email", SqlDbType.DateTime, 8);
           cmd4.Parameters["@Email"].Value = sdt;
           cmd4.Parameters.Add("@FID", SqlDbType.VarChar, 10);
           cmd4.Parameters["@FID"].Value = FID1;
           cmd4.ExecuteNonQuery();
           cn.Close();
           log.Debug("Info : Insert the Email Sent Date of the faculty");
       }
       else
       {
           ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "validation", "<script language='javascript'>alert('Email cannot be sent')</script>");
       }




   }
   log.Debug("Info : Function used to send mail");
}

public void sendMail(String toemail)
{


    try
    {


        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
        mail.To.Add(toemail);
        mail.From = new MailAddress("manipal.mcis1@gmail.com");
        mail.Subject = "Remember Mail";
        // string Body = "Please update profile";
        //mail.Body = Body;
        mail.Body = "  Dear Sir/Madam \n\n\n Please update your profile. . \n\n\n Thanks & Regards \n\n\n MCIS,Manipal.";
        //mail.Body = "<html><body> <h2" + "align=center>Dear Sir/Madam" + "</h2> Please update ur profile</body></html>";
        SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
        smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        smtp.Port = 584;
        smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("manipal.mcis1@gmail.com", "manipal15");
        smtp.EnableSsl = true;
        smtp.Send(mail);


    }
catch (SmtpException ex)
    {

   string msg = "Mail cannot be sent:";
        msg += ex.Message;
        log.Debug("Error: Inside catch block of Mail sending");
        log.Error("Error msg:" + ex);
        log.Error("Stack trace:" + ex.StackTrace);


        throw new Exception(msg);

    }
```

This also arrises with another issue that is whenever it enters `for` loop its executing the
`send(tomail)` function even if it is invalid along with this `ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "validation", "<script language='javascript'>alert('Email sent  on " + test + "')</script>");` line is also executed at every instance.i need to make this work out only when `valid EmailID` and proper  `smtp port` is available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try these lines of code it will work

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    //string vv;
    //vv = (string)Session["FID"];
    DateTime sdt = DateTime.Today;

    SqlCommand cmd4 = new SqlCommand();

    int flag=0;


   String test = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd.MM.yyy");
   for (int i = 0; i <= GridView1.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
   {

       string toemail = GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Text;
       string FID1 = GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Text;
       GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[i];
       CheckBox Ckbox = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("CheckBoxMark1");
       if (Ckbox.Checked == true)
       {

           sendMail(toemail);
           flag = 1;
           //ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "validation", "<script language='javascript'>alert('Email send Succesfully')</script>");
       }

       if (flag == 1)
       {
           //ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "validation", "<script language='javascript'>alert('Email sent  on " + test + "')</script>");

           cn.Open();
           //cmd4.CommandText = "Insert into TrackingFaculty_det  (EmailsentDate)  values (@EmailsentDate) WHERE FID=@FID";
           cmd4.CommandText = "update TrackingFaculty_det SET EmailsentDate=@Email WHERE FID=@FID  ";
           cmd4.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
           cmd4.Connection = cn;

           cmd4.Parameters.Clear();


           cmd4.Parameters.Add("@Email", SqlDbType.DateTime, 8);
           cmd4.Parameters["@Email"].Value = sdt;
           cmd4.Parameters.Add("@FID", SqlDbType.VarChar, 10);
           cmd4.Parameters["@FID"].Value = FID1;
           cmd4.ExecuteNonQuery();
           cn.Close();
           log.Debug("Info : Insert the Email Sent Date of the faculty");
       }




   }
   log.Debug("Info : Function used to send mail");
}

public void sendMail(String toemail)
{


    try
    {


        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
        mail.To.Add(toemail);
        mail.From = new MailAddress("manipal.mcis1@gmail.com");
        mail.Subject = "Remember Mail";
        // string Body = "Please update profile";
        //mail.Body = Body;
        mail.Body = "  Dear Sir/Madam \n\n\n Please update your profile. . \n\n\n Thanks & Regards \n\n\n MCIS,Manipal.";
        //mail.Body = "<html><body> <h2" + "align=center>Dear Sir/Madam" + "</h2> Please update ur profile</body></html>";
        SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
        smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        smtp.Port = 587;
        smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("manipal.mcis1@gmail.com", "manipal15");
        smtp.EnableSsl = true;
        smtp.Send(mail);


    }
    catch (SmtpException ex)
    {


        string msg = "Mail cannot be sent because of the server problem:";
        msg += ex.Message;
        log.Debug("Error: Inside catch block of Mail sending");
        log.Error("Error msg:" + ex);
        log.Error("Stack trace:" + ex.StackTrace);

        Response.Write(msg);
        //throw new Exception(msg);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The time that it needs is the time it needs to "understand" that something is not ok (tehre could different reasons that smtp fails, naturally) .

In you concrete code I see that you *re* - raise an exception, which is according to the your requirements is not what you want, so probabbly better solution could be:

```
    catch (SmtpException ex)
    {

       string msg = "Mail cannot be sent:";
         msg += ex.Message;
         log.Debug("Error: Inside catch block of Mail sending");
         log.Error("Error msg:" + ex);
         log.Error("Stack trace:" + ex.StackTrace);


         SendAsyncMessage(msg);//just an example

    }
```

For client side notification you can use whatever you want. There are different libraries for that:

- [Toast from John Papa](http://www.johnpapa.net/toastr100beta/)
- [Bootstrap3 alerts](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#alerts)

and so  on ...

If this is not what you're asking for, please clarify.

Comment: Thats looks good but if i use `MessageBox` inside catch i think it will show `The name MessageBox` doesnot exixts in current content`

Comment: @SatwikMn: considering that SMTP execution is async in your case, you have to wait for response on client side, and in case of exception return just mesagge (OK, FAIL), and *client* shows a message to the user.

Comment: So it will take around 25-30 seconds to handle the exception?.you dont think its a very long time to handle the exception?

Comment: @SatwikMn: if the SMTP takes so much time to figure out that it fails, it's probably sysadmin issue more then code. But that may not even a problem, if a user notified about failure in some way.

Comment: What if i used `Response.Writeline(msg);` instead of `SendAsyncMessage(msg);`